# Let $A$ be a square matrix that commutes with its transpose. Show that the nullspaces of $A$ and $A^T$ coincide.

Tags: matrices

Am completely stuck on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can this question possibly deserve an upvote?

Comment: I appreciate that this isn't the right way to go about things, but I am completely flummoxed. Don't even know how to start this question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $Ax = 0$ and look at $\|A^Tx\|^2 = x^T A A^T x$